# Pig Flatten without nulls

Tags: apache-pig

I have a pig bag with

```
(1139-50052,Aquatic,Consumer,6,makarina,2,{(),(Unknown)})
(1139-50052,Aquatic,Consumer,6,jabong,2,{(),(),(),(Unknown)})
```

I need to flatten it without nulls.

```
(1139-50052,Aquatic,Consumer,6,makarina,2,Unknown)
(1139-50052,Aquatic,Consumer,6,jabong,2,Unknown)
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option could be you can pass the bag inside `BagToString()` function, so that null values will be discarded and then split your bag value based on delimiter `'_'`.

```
FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(BagToString(BagName),'_+'))
```

Other than your input it will work for other combination also, sample example below.

**input**

```
1139-50052      Aquatic Consumer        6       makarina        2       {(),(Unknown)}
1139-50052      Aquatic Consumer        6       jabong  2       {(),(),(),(Unknown)}
1139-50052      Aquatic Consumer        6       test1   2       {(unknown1),(),(),(Unknown2)}
1139-50052      Aquatic Consumer        6       test2   2       {(unknown1),(unknown2),(),(Unknown3)}
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage() AS (f0,f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,B:{T:(f7)});
B = FOREACH A GENERATE f0,f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(BagToString(B),'_+'));
DUMP B;
```

**Output:**

```
(1139-50052,Aquatic,Consumer,6,makarina,2,Unknown)
(1139-50052,Aquatic,Consumer,6,jabong,2,Unknown)
(1139-50052,Aquatic,Consumer,6,test1,2,unknown1,Unknown2)
(1139-50052,Aquatic,Consumer,6,test2,2,unknown1,unknown2,Unknown3)
```